# Finding the index of minimum value in a row in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I can't seem to get my head around how to do this - I am new to Python and this kind of work with arrays. I have a large array, say:

```
array([[119., 323.,  42., 277., 401.],
       [122., 326.,  39., 278., 10.],
       [125., 329.,  36., 12., 407.],
       ...,
       [308., 314., 469., 188., 266.],
       [308., 314., 469., 188., 266.],
       [308., 314., 469., 188., 266.]])
```

I would like to find the column index of the minimum value in each row. For instance for the first 3 rows would give [2, 4, 3....]. I have experimented with .min() and np.where(), for instance:

```
np.where(array == array.min())
```

But I just can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: `indexes = [x.index(min(x)) for x in the_array]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use numpy [`argmin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
np.argmin(a, axis=1)
```

where `a` is your numpy array.